# How to implement RecyclerView Page Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement to scroll Recyclerview in one page increments. Each page containing a grid of 3 by 3 items.

I have used GridLayoutManager to implement the grid, now I am trying to override the onScrolled() method to implement scroll by page. I want each horizontal scroll to display 3 items which represents 1 page.

Here is portion of my code

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sub_category_list_recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), rowCount, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    adapter = new SubCategoryGridLayoutAdapter(new ArrayList<SubCategoryViewItem>());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {


           int visibleItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
           int totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
           int  pastVisiblesItems = gridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
           int lastitemPos = gridLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();



            if (dx > 0) {
                //Right Scrolling
                int moreItems = lastitemPos + 9;
                if (totalItemCount > moreItems){
                    gridLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(moreItems, 0);
                }else {
                    gridLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(totalItemCount, 0);
                }

            }
            if (dx < 0) {
                //Left Scrolling
                int lessItems = pastVisiblesItems + 9;
                if (lessItems < totalItemCount){
                    gridLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(lessItems, 0);
                }else {
                    gridLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(totalItemCount, 0);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reading of this question, in support library 25.1.0 was added [PageSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper) (for simulation of ViewPager - only scrolling item by item) or [LinearSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper) (moves to the item that is closest to the middle of RecycleView).

Usage is simple :
`PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(rvYourRecycleViewName)`